# Auto Play video in ios app

Tags: function, video, autoplay

My project is just started. I would like to capture a video and send to another user in this app and AUTO-PLAY VIDEO in this user app. Is it possible? If this function works, how can I control the data usage? Please give me some directions.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: @manetsus Thanks for the information. I am new to IOS development, and at this moments, I only have this idea: Sender sends the captured the video to receiver with timer. When timer triggered, video will auto-play in the receiver IOS app. However I do not know whether it could achieve in IOS app, and how. I need the help from community to introduce me some related docs so I can start with it. Thanks again!